# how to INSERT a NULL value in mysql, taken from a variable. ASP

Tags: mysql, asp-classic, insert, null

lets assume i have a staement variable like this:

```
sql_ins = "INSERT INTO tableName (field1,field2,field3) VALUES ("&var1&","&var2&","&var3&")
```

well, let's say that var1, var2, var3 could be also `null`, and the database has default values as `null`.

the problem is that i could insert a `NULL` value, but if the variable is `null` it will be empty, so the sql_ins should look like:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (4,,)
```

how i could avoid it?

thanks in advance.

real code here:

```
For Each Field in Request.Form
    TheString = Field & "=Request.Form(""" _
    & Field & """)"
    EXECUTE(TheString)
Next

if imm_id <> "" then
'TODO modifica
else 
sql_ins = "INSERT INTO tb_immobile (`IdServizio`, `CodiceAppartamento`, `Nome`, `IdLocalita`, `Localita`, `NumeroPiano`, `Piano`, `NumeroScalini`, `Camere`, `Singole`, `Matrimoniali`, `Bagni`, `Vani`, `IdTipo`, `IdPosizione`, `IdAspetto`, `IdRistrutturato`, `IdAmmobiliato`, `IdStato`, `Mq`, `Annesso`, `IdAnnessoRistrutturato`, `Giardino`, `Terrazza`, `Terreno`, `Cantina`, `AriaCondizionata`, `Ascensore`, `PostiAuto`, `Piscina`, `Tennis`, `IdRiscaldamento`, `Condominio`, `idAllegato`, `idUtente`, `idImportazione`, `idZona`, `idDove`, `homePage`, `codTipoVisaulizzazione`) VALUES "
sql_ins = sql_ins&"(1,"&imm_codice&","&imm_nome&","&imm_provincia&",'"&imm_localita&"',"&imm_npiani&","&imm_piano&","&imm_scalini&","&imm_camere&","&imm_camere_sing&","&imm_camere_mat&","&imm_bagni&","&imm_vani&","&imm_tipo&","&imm_posizione&","&imm_aspetto&","&imm_ristrutturato&","&imm_ammobiliato&","&imm_stato&","&imm_mq&"...  )"


end if
```

in the first for each i create and populate the variables, but some of them should be empty.

Comment: Which data access provider do you use? An dhow you try to insert data. Can you provide a piece of code?

Comment: Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if var1 Is Nothing then var1 = "NULL" end if
```

Comment: this will work on numeric values, becouse during the insert I will write ...,"&var1&",... but if i espect a string value the insert will be ...,' "&var1&" ',... which return in ...,' 'NULL' ', i guess this is not right...

Comment: yes, edited to remove the `'`s, they do not need to be used here

Comment: how can the single quote problem persist if you have removed the single quotes?

Comment: because single quotes are in the statement, i mean:
to insert a value of a string field, i must pass the variable with the single queotes like ... **'** "&var1&" **'**...

Comment: i'm thinking about making an insert followed by an update in which i create the fields only if there is a value...

Comment: You could take the single quotes out of the statement and use: `If var1 Is Nothing then var1 = "NULL" else var1 = "'" + var1 + "'" end if`